# Git ignoring pager settings?

Tags: git

I am trying to set up the pager settings in `git` in such a way so that the screen is cleared when I quit my `less` session created by calling `git diff`, basically the opposite of what `less -X` does. However, nothing I try gives me the desired effect.

I have `core.pager=less -FRS` setting in my `.gitconfig` file, and calling `git config --list` shows it as such. But the pager keeps behaving as if I still have the `-X` flag set, even calling `git init` to have the `.gitconfig` file re-read has no effect.

What could be the reason for this? My git version is 2.21.0.windows.1.

**EDIT:** This seems to be an issue with just the `-X` flag behavior. Other settings like line chop/fold `-F` and tab size `-x4` are respected accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git always exports some setting for the `LESS` environment variable.  (This is true even if you set `core.pager` to, say, `cat`!)  The *way* it does this is simple:

- If `$LESS` is set, it passes it on unmolested.  (This is true even if it's set to an empty string.)
- Otherwise it exports `LESS=FRX`.

Then it runs `core.pager` or `$GIT_PAGER` or whatever pager is selected by the rest of the settings.

Since `less` itself obeys `$LESS` values, you get `-X` behavior.  If you don't want it, you can, as you saw, either set `$LESS` yourself (so that Git passes it through unmolested) or, e.g., set `core.pager` to `less +X` so that the command-line `+X` overrides the environment `-X`.  The latter is a special feature of `less` rather than a feature of Git: all the env settings can be overridden by the command line.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does `-+X` mean? I've seen this format in another answer somewhere.

Comment: Less treats -+<letter> the same as +<letter>, for programs that think options can only be prefixed with `-`. (That's kind of a special case, since the POSIX standard is that options *are* prefixed with `-`.)

Answer (score 0):

Well. Adding `export LESS="-x4 $LESS"` to my `.bashrc` seems to have done the trick. It also seems that `$LESS` flags are applied on top of flags in `core.pager`.

I still have no idea why it works though.

My env variables:

```bash
$ echo LESS=\"$LESS\" PAGER=\"$PAGER\" GIT_PAGER=\"$GIT_PAGER\"
LESS="-x4 " PAGER="" GIT_PAGER=""
```